# How is physical information created?

Tags: entropy, universe, information

I am not a physist, so please forgive my ignorance. I am an avid reader of popular science though. So I read about the problem of information seemingly lost at a black hole horizon.

But my question is about the creation of the information. My limited understanding is that our Univers had a very low entropy at creation and the entropy of the entire Univese is increasing (is it a closed system where second law is applicable?). At the same time the information - presumably present at the creation - is preserved.

The question is: can/does new information arise as a result of local organization - as in dynamic equlibrium for example? Or is it neseccary that the overall increasing entropy results in a zero sum? In later case - can the increase of entropy be equated to the information contained in the newly created order. I suspect that the observer has something to do with that. But the observer itself contains the information. Is it a paradox?

Answer (score -1):

I am not a physicist either, but lately I've been entertaining new ideas relating to information, in particular. One idea is that all instruments we use to make measurements with are conspiring to give us the impression that all phenomena beyond what our senses can directly experience are really there. Like when you put a voltmeter to a battery. We can only trust that the instrument is not just pulling a value on the readout from something other than the measured value. 
To take this a step further, how can we prove, without any shadow of a doubt, that our eyes are not just being fooled into seeing the world as we think it should be. This is where quantum weirdness comes in.  If there is no observer, there is no measurement. 
You could call this the "conspiracy to convince materialists that the universe is real."